# uploading an <img> to a remote server

Tags: php, upload, image

What I am able to do right now is to get the content of a canvas and convert it to a png using img.src = toDataUrl().

What I would like to do now is to upload that img on a remote server using PHP. Is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: What kind of remote server? FTP? A HTTP server running an application that has a form that accepts file uploads?

Comment: Define the following: "the content", "a canvas", "toDataUrl()", "on a remote server", "this". Are you trying to take the contents of an HTML5 canvas, and upload them in PNG format to a webserver?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Then please update your question's title, text and tags with the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how it's done [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=177683) (the second post). You need to have the cURL PHP extension installed on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Send the result of canvas.toDataURL()

```
var imageInfo = canvas.toDataURL(); /* sample: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..." */
```

Direct way to create the png file:

```
<?php
$image = fopen($imageInfo, 'r');
file_put_contents("fileName.png", $image);
fclose($image);
?>
```